# Iteration loop inside another loop

Tags: java, iterator, nested-loops

Is there any way I can use an Iterator inside another loop?
I am asking this because I can't find a way to bring the iterator at the start of the list again after the first loop is done and therefore at a second loop the iter.hasNext() will give me false

```
Iterator iter = list.iterator();
for (int i=0;i<30;i++)
{
 while (iter.hasNext())
 {
  ...
 }

}
```

Comment: Uhhh... move the first line inside the `for`?

Comment: Well mind stops working sometimes... I don't know why I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Iterator iter;
for (int i=0;i<30;i++)
{
    iter = list.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext())
     {
      ...
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just reset the iterator in the outer loop:

```
for (int i=0;i<30;i++) {
    Iterator iter = list.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Object obj = iter.next();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The iterator was consumed during first cycle of a loop (i==0). To fix the problem u need to reinitialise the `item` reference inside a loop. Best!